# What is the time axis array after we convolve two functions in Matlab after sampling it with frequency \$f_s\$?

Tags: matlab, convolution

Suppose we have a continuous time function \$f(t)\$ , we sample it at frequency \$f_s, (t = -5:1/f_s:5)\$, and store it in an array \$a\$ in Matlab. Now we convolve it with itself using \$b = conv(a,a)\$. What is the new time axis array for the convolved function stored discretely in array \$b\$ ?

Answer (score 0):

the new x-axis should be the lag between the signals.
Since your signal is a digital signal, the x-axis is N, where N is the number of samples ahead or behind the the original signal.